# Hodge numbers of base of fibration

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fibration, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth complex manifold which is a fibration over a complex base manifold $B$. Supposing we know the details of the fibration, is it possible from knowledge of the Hodge numbers of $X$ to extract information about the Hodge numbers of $B$?

Comment: I am not sure but I believe that the Hodge numbers of $B \times F$ should be the same as the Hodge numbers of $X$. Does it help ?

Comment: I made an answer. There is no contradiction with what you said, it is very specific to the situation where $X$ is a proper smooth complex variety. (Also you probably meant $b_1(S^1 \times S^2) = 1 \neq 0 = b_1(S^3)$ ? )

Comment: I found this article :
arxiv.org/abs/1602.06674 According to this, in some cases you can use singular cohomology, to compute sheaf cohomology .By Dolbeault theorem, sheaf cohomology gives you the Hodge numbers.
And when using singular cohomology, there is the Serre spectral sequence which relates the cohomologies of the total space X and that of the base.
May be this is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me expand my comment. I need to assume that $X$ and $B$ are algebraic, compact and smooth. Then, the Hodge numbers of $X$ coincide with the Hodge numbers of $F \times B$.

For see this, consider the Grothendieck ring of varieties $K_0(\text{Var}/\Bbb C)$. This is the ring generated by varieties over $\Bbb C$, quotiented by the "scissor relation" $[X] = [Y] + [X \backslash Y]$ where $Y \subset X$ is closed. The product is defined as $[X] \cdot [Y] = [X \times Y]$.

Now we have the following theorem :

> **Theorem** : There is a ring morphism : $P_{Hodge} : K_0(\text{Var}/\Bbb C) \to \Bbb Z[u^{\pm 1},v^{\pm 1}]$ such that if $X$ is smooth and proper then $ P_{Hodge}(X) = \sum_{p,q} h^{p,q}u^pv^q$

In particular, this means that for compute $P_{Hodge}$ you can cut and glue as you like as long as you finish with proper smooth varieties. For example, $P_{Hodge}(\Bbb P^1 \times \Bbb P^1) = P_{Hodge}(\Bbb A^1 \times \Bbb A^1) + 1 + uv + uv = (uv)^2 + 2uv + 1$ which indeed coincide with the usual Hodge number for $\Bbb P^1 \times \Bbb P^1$.

Now it is clear that in $K_0(\text{Var}/\Bbb C)$ we have $[X] = [B][F]$ if $X$ is a fibration with base $B$ and fiber $F$, so the claims follows.

This gives you all the informations you can have, with the fact that $$ h^{p,q}(X \times Y) = \sum_{u+v = p, r+s = q}h^{u,r}(X)h^{v,s}(Y)$$

**Edit** : In fact, for the more general case of a fibration one can also carry similar computations, for simplicity let me assume that $X \to B$ is a fibration with finitely many singular fibers $F_1, \dots, F_n$. Then we have the equality $[X] - \sum_i ([F_i] - [F])= [B][F]$ where $F$ is the generic fiber, and this can gives you information about the Hodge numbers of $B$ assuming that you can compute everything else.

Comment: This is a really nice theorem; thanks a lot for this. I will spend some time trying to appreciate it fully. If I'm interpreting it right, this result holds only for a fibre bundle, rather than more general fibrations (where some of the fibres may have degenerated for example), but maybe it is not possible to make a more general statement.

Comment: Exactly, it is crucial that all fiber are the same else $[X] = [B][F]$ does not holds. Notice that there is also the same theorem with Betti number i.e the Poincaré polynomial, it is useful for compute e.g the cohomology of toric varieties. The proof use that $K_0$ is generated by the smooth projective variety with the unique relation $Bl_Z(X) - E = X - Z$ (Bittner theorem). If you want more informations about it I guess the keyword is "motivic integration". And yes I'm not sure it's possible to compute it for a more general fibration using Grothendieck ring, because ...

Comment: ... because it is pretty tricky to compute $P_{Hodge}(Y)$ is $Y$ is not proper or singular, unless expressing $Y $ as a difference of closed sets where you already know $P_{Hodge}$. But I would be happy to see a more general formula !

Comment: @diracula : In fact it is also possible to compute something in the case of a singular fibration, see my edit, I think you can generalize it to any kind of fibration, just keep cutting until you get disjoint fiber bundle and then you can compute everything in term of the usual Hodge numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting edit. I guess this can be used only in situations where $[F_i]-[F]$ makes sense as a smooth complex manifold?

Comment: @diracula Not at all, remember that $P_{Hodge}([F_i] - [F]) = P_{Hodge}([F_i]) - P_{Hodge}(F)$ as $P_{Hodge}$ is a ring morphism. This theorem is simply very strong, in fact this shows that in this case $P_{Hodge}(B)$ is uniquely determined as $P_{Hodge}(F) = 1 + \dots$ is invertible, so this give the close formula $P_{Hodge}(B) = P_{Hodge}(F) ^{-1} \cdot (P_{Hodge}([X]) - \sum_i P_{Hodge}(F_i) + n P_{Hodge} ([F]))$.
As I said I think it should work for any fibration, for example... (continued after)

Comment: For example, the locus where $\pi : X \to B$ is not a submersion is a proper hypersurface $B_1 \subset B$. This give (I write $P$ instead of $P_{Hodge}$ for simplicity) $P(X) = P(B - B_1)P(F) + P(\pi^{-1}B_1)$. This better because $X_1 := \pi^{-1}(B_1)$ as smaller dimension, so again you can restrict $\pi$ to $X_1$ and continue like this.

Comment: Only one annoying point: a submersion of algebraic manifold need not be Zariski locally trivial... On the other hand, for Zariski locally trivial fibration, one may use log de Rham complex and things like that to show the Hodge polynomial of X is the same as product of that of B and F.

Comment: @lee : you are right this is a problem. However, if $X$ is projective and $f$ a smooth map then it still holds (but this is not a very usual situation I agree).

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Why's that?

Comment: @lee : Because the Leray spectral sequence degenerates at $E_2$ by Deligne-Blanchard. But you have to know monodromy in fact. Now if $f : X \to B$ is smooth, projective and $B$ simply connected then we are good. But that's a very strong hypothesis ...

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice your assumption of B. Right, in general I think it's hard to find rational curves inside moduli space.

Comment: It should be noted that the Hodge numbers of the total space of a complex manifold $X$ which holomorphically fibers over $B$ with fiber $F$ are not in general those of $B\times F$ if $F,X,B$ are not smooth varieties but rather just general compact complex manifolds (as asked for by the OP) . As an example, consider the holomorphic fiber bundle involving the Hopf manifold $S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times S^3 \to CP^1$.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic : This is right, the map should be algebraic, thanks for your comment.