# Cohomology of projective bundle only depends on base and fiber?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles

Let $P\to X$ be a $\mathbb P^n$ bundle. Is it true that all the (co)homology group only depends on $X$ and $n$ (and independent of the transform funcions) ?

Comment: Yes for the cohomology groups, no for the ring structure. You have $H^*(P)=H^*(X)[\xi]/(\xi^{n+1}+c_1\xi^n+...+c_{n+1}\xi^0)$ where $c_1,...,c_n$ are the Chern classes and $\xi$ is of degree 1.

Comment: @Roland The last $x_{n+1}$ should be $c_{n+1}$? and could you write a little more about how you get this?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. Look for projective bundle theorem (it is stated here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_bundle).

Comment: @Roland Thanks! You can post as an answer if you want.

Comment: Corrected the typo in the comment. ;)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks, I cannot edit my own comment after 5 minutes. I guess I will have to answer this questions and a few others so that in an hundred years I will have this privilege ;)

Comment: @Roland My guess is that you'll never be able to do that unless you are a moderator, heh.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Ok, I guess it all right. I am writing an answer at this moment. I will still do. This will correct an other mistake from my comment : $\xi$ is of degree 2 and not 1 of course.

Comment: In fact for every locally trivial algebraic fibration $f : Y \to X$ we have $H^*(Y) \cong H^*(F \times X)$ where $F$ is the fiber (over $\mathbb C^).

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet That would be very nice! Could you give a reference?

Comment: @Akatsuki This  is a nontrivial result, see this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461550/hodge-numbers-of-base-of-fibration/2461709#2461709 (this is even true for Hodge numbers so of course it implies the version).But in fact, what I wrote was a bit misleading : we only have isomorphism as a group and not in general as a ring (as Roland already said). Edit : and I don't know a reference, but googling "Grothendieck ring of varieties" and also "Bittner's theorem" should give you some references.

Comment: ( And also : you should assume usual hypothesis (smothness and projectivity of $Y,X$. Else there might be counterexample,e.g the map $\mathbb C^3 \backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb P^2$. )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is true and this is essentially the content of the projective bundle theorem. You can find it stated here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_bundle

But note however that even if the cohomology groups $H^*(P)$ only depends on the base scheme $X$, this is not true for the ring structure. In fact we have :
$$ H^*(P)=H^*(X)[\xi]/(\xi^n+c_1\xi^{n-1}+...+c_{n+1}\xi^0)$$
where $\xi\in H^2(P)$ is of degree 2 and is the class $c_1(\mathcal{O}_{P}(1))$ of the tautological bundle, and $c_1,...,c_{n+1}\in H^*(X)$ are the Chern classes of $P$.

Comment: I am sure this is true if the $\mathbb{P}^n$ bundle comes from a vector bundle because you can play around with a tautological bundle, the Leray-Hirsch Theorem etc. But do all $\mathbb P^n$ bundles come from vector bundles? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @ThomasRot No you are right, there are projective bundle which does not come from vector bundles. I was being sloppy here. Now I wonder if this is still true. I will think about it and edit the answer. If you know more, please make your own answer !

Comment: I do not know more unfortunately.

Comment: Just a note: some people use the term projective bundle specifically to refer to projectivizations of vector bundles, and refer to fibrations that do not arise in this way as Brauer-Severi varieties.

Comment: You say $c_1, \dots, c_{n+1}$ are the Chern classes of $P$. Do you mean the Chern classes of the underlying vector bundle?